# How can I retrieve environment variables from remote system in Python?

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables

I'm trying to retrieve environment variables of a remote Linux server in Python. Alternatively, if I could use the variable name in the command I'm executing, that'd be great as well. The calls I'm making should work, as far as I can tell, but I'm getting back garbage. I have set up public-key authentication, so no password required.

Effort 1:

```
devdir = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", connectstring, "echo $DEVDIR"])
```

Effort 2:

```
ret = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", connectstring, 
    "$DEVDIR/{0}".format(testpath)])
```

`connectstring` is user@ip and works fine. `$DEVDIR` is the remote variable I want to use and contains a path. `testpath` is the path to the script I'm trying to execute, rooted at `$DEVDIR`.

Effort 1 returns "\n", Effort 2 fails to resolve $DEVDIR remotely.

---

Effort 3:

```
import paramiko
...
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(ip, user)    # succeeds
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("echo $DEVDIR")
```

result: stdout.readlines() = "\n"

Comment: are you sure that `$DEVDIR` is set appropriately? If it works if you log in manually, but fails at remote command execution, I suspect it to be set at login sessions only...

Comment: @glglgl, that may be it--$DEVDIR is set by .bashrc. I'll try exporting the variable in .profile.

Comment: I tried exporting in .profile with no luck. I also tried executing `ssh.exec_command("source ~/.bashrc")` followed by the `ssh.exec_command("echo $DEVDIR")` command and got the same `\n` result.

Comment: I think you might have to remotely execute `sh -c "echo $DEVDIR"` because it's the shell which sets it, although it might make more sense just to remotely execute `cat .bashrc`, and pull it from there directly.

Comment: as just written in my answer: what does `ssh.exec_command("env")` give? (Not the full output, please; just the relevant part.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the environment variable is set in `.bashrc`, you can force the remote command to run under a login shell with the `-l` option. The following...

```
devdir = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", connectstring, "sh -l -c 'echo $DEVDIR'"])
```

...works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Executing a command va SSH does not produce a login session. So some variables might not be set.

You can check this by replacing the variable with another one such as `$HOSTNAME` or `$HOST` or `$SSH_CONNECTION` or by executing the `env` command.

A solution might be to put the variable assignment into a file which is executed in a non-login session as well. `.bashrc` should be fine, however; maybe there is a flaw somewhere inside.

Comment: You are right: `ssh.exec_command("env")` shows a much shorter list of environment variables that demonstrate that .bashrc isn't being loaded.

Comment: I don't think this will work. From the `ssh` manpage, "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell", which sounds like you don't even get a shell.

Comment: @Aya The "instead" refers to the "login" part of "login shell". You get a shell, which gets the complete command line transferred over the line. Try `ssh localhost ps $$` and see how `$$` is translated into the real process ID. So that works definitely via a shell on the contacted host.

Comment: `ssh localhost ps $$` will show the process info for the shell which is executing `ssh`, because `$$` is substituted by the shell before it executes the command. If you just ask `ps` to show processes associated with the current session, with `ssh localhost ps`, you'll see the the remote 'shell' is actually just `ps`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
devdir = subprocess.check_output(["ssh -i", connectstring, "echo $DEVDIR", FALSE])
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it should help.

Comment: Doesn't work. Adding `-i` gives error `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, and adding `False` (not `FALSE`) gives error `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: If adding argument `-i`, it should be done as a separate argument and not added to the command name. And then `-i` is missing the identity file name. And what `FALSE` resp. `False` should be good for in this context is beyond my understanding.